# How to insert data in a custom function that comes from an add-on sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I'm trying to get data from a sidebar and use it as a custom function input.

[image]

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I don't think that the server can communicate with the client unless the client is polling the server.  So you can select a cell on the spreadsheet and perform an action and the side bar that sends data from the client to the server and can even return something back to the server.  The server can figure out which is the active page and cell and provide some sort of input to that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets doesn't include references to sidebar data and custom functions can't access sidebar either.